# C# wrapper and Callbacks

Tags: c#, callback, wrapper

I'm in the process of writing a C# wrapper for Dallmeier Common API light (Camera & Surviellance systems) and I've never written a wrapper before, but I have used the Canon EDSDK C# wrapper. So I'm using the Canon wrapper as a guide to writing the Dallmeier wrapper.

I'm currently having issues with wrapping a callback. In the API manual it has the following:

**dlm_connect**

```
int(unsigned long uLWindowHandle,   
    const char * strIP,  
    const char* strUser1,  
    const char* strPwd1,  
    const char* strUser2,  
    const char* strPwd2,   
    void (*callback)(void *pParameters, void *pResult, void *pInput),   
    void * pInput)
```

**Arguments**
- ulWindowhandle - handle of the window that is passed to the ViewerSDK to display video and messages there
- strUser1/2 - names of the users to log in. If only single user login is used strUser2 is
- NULL
- strPwd1/2 - passwords of both users. If strUser2 is NULL strPwd2 is ignored.

**Return**
This function creates a SessionHandle that has to be passed

**Callback**
pParameters will be structured:
- unsigned long ulFunctionID
- unsigned long ulSocketHandle, //handle to socket of the established connection
- unsigned long ulWindowHandle,
- int SessionHandle, //session handle of the session created
- const char * strIP,
- const char* strUser1,
- const char* strPwd1,
- const char* strUser2,
- const char * strPWD2
pResult is a pointer to an integer, representing the result of the operation. Zero on success.
Negative values are error codes.

So from what I've read on the Net and Stack Overflow - C# uses delegates for the purpose of callbacks. So I create a my Callback function :

```
public delegate uint DallmeierCallback(DallPparameters pParameters, IntPtr pResult, IntPtr pInput);
```

I create the connection function

```
[DllImport("davidapidis.dll")]
public extern static int dlm_connect(int ulWindowHandle, string strIP, string strUser1, string strPwd1, string strUser2, string strPwd2, DallmeierCallback inDallmeierFunc
```

And (I think) the DallPParameters as a struct :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DallPParameters
{
  public int ulfunctionID;
  public int ulsocketHandle;
  public int ulWindowHandle;
  ...
}
```

All of this is in my wrapper class.
Am I heading in the right direction or is this completely wrong?
Then in my Dallmeier class I have the following:

```
    private DallmeierAPI dallmeierAPI;  
    private DallmeierSDK.DallmeierCallback dallCallbackHandler;  
    private GCHandle handle;  
    private IntPtr pResult;  
    private IntPtr pInput;  

    internal Dallmeier()
    {
        this.dallmeierAPI = DallmeierAPI.Instance;

        registerEvents();
    }

    private void registerEvents()
    {
        // Register Callback Events
        dallCallbackHandler = new DallmeierSDK.DallmeierCallback(pParameters, pResult, pInput); // Error: Method Name expected

        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(dallCallbackHandler);
    }

    private void unregisterEvents()
    {
        handle.Free();
    }

    private DallmeierSDK.DallPParameters pParameters(int ulfunctionID, int ulSocketHandl, int ulWindowHandle, int SessionHandle, string strIP, string strUser1, string strPwd1, string strUser2, string strPwd)
    {
        // what goes in here : Error not all code paths return a value
    }


}
```

So when I register the callback its saying a Method Name expected?
and pParameters is expecting a return value?

Comment: Your callback method needs to match the signature of the delegate type.  You would then write `new DallmeierSDK.DallmeierCallback(SomeMethodName)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly on the right track.

However, C `long`s are (I believe) 32-bit, and map to C# `int`s.
Also, after calling the function, you must keep a managed reference to the delegate instance that you passed to make sure that the delegate doesn't get garbage collected.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the reference.  I forgot to keep a reference to the delegate around once... that was some fun. :)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I've done an edit on the post and changed the longs to ints.   Do I use - GCHandle.Alloc - to keep a managed reference?

Comment: Or just make a field in your class (assuming the class will last long enough)

Comment: I've edit my post to include details on calling the function which I'm having some issue with.