# C# wrapper for array of three pointers

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, wrapper

I'm currently working on a C# wrapper to work with Dallmeier Common API light.
See previous posting: [C# wrapper and Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430089/c-wrapper-and-callbacks)

I've got pretty much everything 'wrapped' but I'm stuck on wrapping a callback which contains an array of three pointers & an array integers:

**dlm_setYUVDataCllback**

```
int(int SessionHandle, void (*callback) (long IPlayerID, unsigned char** yuvData,  
    int* pitch, int width, int height, int64_t ts, char* extData))
```

**Function** Set callback, to receive current YUV image.
**Arguments** SessionHandle: handle to current session.
**Return** PlayerID (see callback).
**Callback**  - IPlayerId: id to the Player object
              - yuvData: array of three pointers to Y, U and V part of image
                The YUV format used is YUV420 planar (not packed).
                char *y = yuvData[0];
                char *u = yuvData[1];
                char *v = yuvData[2];
              - pitch: array of integers for pitches for Y, U and V part of image
              - width: intrinsic width of image.
              - height
              - ts : timestamp of current frame
              - extData: additional data to frame

How do I go about wrapping this in c#?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unsigned char** yuvData` should be defined as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=3)] IntPtr[] yuvData`

You will then get an array of 3 IntPtrs. You can the read the actual data using the Marshal.Read or Marshal.Copy.

Comment: Thanks logicnp. Just a followup on this, i have created a struct with the parameters as above but what should 'Int64_t' be in c# and do I use the same MashalAs for the 'pitch' which is also an array of integers e.g. [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=1)] IntPtr[] pitch

Comment: int64_t should be defined as long (which is also 64-bits in c#).
For the pitch, your definition is correct if 'pitch' is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: How and Were do I use the Marshal.Read or Marshal.Copy

Comment: @logicnp: I think you meant UnmanagedType.LPArray. ByValArray is only valid on structure fields.