# Convert C++ code to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have code wrote on C++:

```
    char szTempString[1500];
    DWORD dwDataLength = PacketBuffer.m_Length - (sizeof(ether_header) + pIpHeader->ip_hl*4 + pTcpHeader->th_off*4);
    PCHAR pData = (PCHAR)pEthHeader + (sizeof(ether_header) + pIpHeader->ip_hl*4 + pTcpHeader->th_off*4);

    // If packet contains any data - process it
    if (dwDataLength)
    {
        //
        // Copy packet payload into the temporary string
        //
        memcpy (szTempString, pData, dwDataLength);
```

C#:

```
char[] szTempString = new char[1500];
var dwDataLength = (int)PacketBuffer.m_Length -
(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (ETHER_HEADER)) + (pIpHeader->IPLenVer & 0xF)*4 + (pTcpHeader->Off & 0xF)*4);

var pData = (IntPtr)pEthHeader + (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ETHER_HEADER)) +
(pIpHeader->IPLenVer & 0xF) * 4 + (pTcpHeader->Off & 0xF) * 4);

if(dwDataLength != 0)
{
    Marshal.Copy(pData,szTempString, 0, dwDataLength);
    Console.WriteLine(szTempString);
}
```

**ehter_header, pIp_header** and other is structs, they are converted to C#.
The var **szTempString** contains strange data. Have I converted the **pData** and function **memcpy** properly?
Thanks.
PS. This is WinPkFilter library. Maybe somebody used it in C#?

Comment: Can you please look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559308/using-marshal-copy-correctly) . It talks about how to use Marshal.Copy correctly. Also this [one](http://forum.soft32.com/pda/Marshal-Copy-char-includes-terminating-null-ftopict49073.html) might be useful too.

Comment: I don't know C# so this might be irrelevant, but `pData` in the C++ code is treated as a `char*`, and looks like it's treated as a `int*` in your C# code. That's two very different things when you do pointer arithmetics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET's char is actually unicode, not like in c++. You should at least replace char by byte. Then, when you ultimately want a string from bytes, use the Encoding class, like this: Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)...

Answer (score 1):

have you added a [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)] before your struct?

Comment: No, can you tell me more details

Comment: here is an example: http://sharperscience.blogspot.com/2008/11/interop-example-marshalling-structures.html