# c# wrapper and issue with protected memory

Tags: c#, memory, wrapper, protected

So I've now progressed to having an almost functioning wrapper.
Other posts regarding my wrapper issues are:
[C# wrapper and Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430089/c-wrapper-and-callbacks) &
[C# wrapper for array of three pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444687/c-wrapper-for-array-of-three-pointers)

I use the wrapper to establish a connection to the Dallmeier using the following:

```
_dallmeier.SessionHandle = DallmeierSDK.dlm_connect(_handle, _ip, "", _pass, null, null, connectionCallback, pInPut)
```

This returns the session handler. After awhile I get a AccessVoilationException about attempted to read or write protected memory.

I think this has something to do with using Marshal.Read and/or Marshal.Copy (as stated in one of the posts above) but I'm not sure where I use these commands.

Can some please advise me on this and/or examples?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try wrapping your code in a `fixed` block, to prevent moving the pointer in memory or being GC-collected.